# Defining Modules VS.NET vs F# Interactive

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have written this code which compiles and works perfectly in VS.NET 2010

```
module ConfigHandler
open System
open System.Xml
open System.Configuration

let GetConnectionString (key : string) =
  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item(key).ConnectionString
```

however when I do a control + A and Alt + Enter to send this to FSI I get an error

ConfigHandler.fs(2,1): error FS0010: Unexpected start of structured construct in definition. Expected '=' or other token.

OK.

So I change my code to

```
module ConfigHandler =
  open System
  open System.Xml
  open System.Configuration

  let GetConnectionString (key : string) =
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item(key).ConnectionString
```

Now Control + A, Alt + Enter  is successful and I FSI nicely tells me

module ConfigHandler = begin
  val GetConnectionString : string -> string
end

However now If I try to compile my code in VS.NET 2010, I get an error message

Files in libraries or multiple-file applications must begin with a namespace or module declaration, e.g. 'namespace SomeNamespace.SubNamespace' or 'module SomeNamespace.SomeModule'

How can I have both? Ability to compile in VS.NET and the ability to send modules to FSI?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a tiny -- but crucial -- difference between your two snippets of code which is to blame here.

F# has two ways to declare a `module`. The first, a "top-level module", is declared like this:

```
module MyModule
// ... code goes here
```

The other way to declare a module is as a "local module", like so:

```
module MyModule =
    // ... code goes here
```

The main differences between the "top-level" and "local" declarations are that the local declaration is followed by an `=` sign and the code within a "local" module **must** be indented.

The reason you get the `ConfigHandler.fs(2,1): error FS0010: Unexpected start of structured construct in definition. Expected '=' or other token.` message for the first snippet is that you can't declare top-level modules in `fsi`.

When you added the `=` sign to your module definition, it changed from a top-level module to a local module. From there, you got the error `Files in libraries or multiple-file applications must begin with a namespace or module declaration, e.g. 'namespace SomeNamespace.SubNamespace' or 'module SomeNamespace.SomeModule'` because local modules must be nested within a top-level module or a namespace. `fsi` doesn't allow you to define namespaces (or top-level modules), so if you want to copy-paste the entire file into `fsi` the only way it'll work is if you use the compilation directives as @pad mentioned. Otherwise, you can simply copy-paste the local module definitions (without the containing namespace) into `fsi` and they should work as expected.

Reference:
[Modules (F#) on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233221.aspx)

Answer (score 10):

The common solution is to keep the first example and create a `fsx` file which references the module:

```
#load "ConfigHandler.fs"
```

You have advantage of loading multiple modules and writing plumbing code for experiment.

If you really want to load `ConfigHandler.fs` directly to F# Interactive, you can use `INTERACTIVE` symbol and [compiler directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233195.aspx):

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#else
module ConfigHandler
#endif
```

which works for both fsi and fsc.