# In F# what does top-level mean?

Tags: scope, f#, shadowing, toplevel

When people talk about F# they sometimes mention the term `top-level`;

what does `top-level` mean?

For example in previous SO Q&A

[Error FS0037 sometimes, very confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36498564/1243762)
[Defining Modules VS.NET vs F# Interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12160038/1243762)
[What the difference between a namespace and a module in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/795270/1243762)
[AutoOpen attribute in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12977466/1243762)
[F# and MEF: Exporting Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35544011/1243762)
[How to execute this F# function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25278986/1243762)

The term also appears regularly in comments but for those Q&A I did not reference them.

The Wikipedia article on [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) touches on this, but has no specifics for F#.

The F# 3.x spec only states:

11.2.1.1 Arity Conformance for Functions and Values

> The parentheses indicate a `top-level` function, which might be a
>   first-class computed expression that computes to a function value,
>   rather than a compile-time function value.

13.1 Custom Attributes

> For example, the STAThread attribute should be placed immediately
>   before a `top-level` “do” statement.

14.1.8 Name Resolution for Type Variables

> It is initially empty for any member or any other `top-level` construct
>   that contains expressions and types.

I suspect the term has different meanings in different contexts:
Scope, F# interactive, shadowing.

If you could also explain the origins from F# predecessor languages, (ML, CAML, OCaml) it would be appreciated.

Lastly I don't plan to mark an answer as accepted for a few days to avoid hasty answers.

Comment: Of interest related to OCaml: [The toplevel system](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual023.html)

Comment: Of interest: [module vs type behavior difference on using F# lambda as actual argument to formal parameter that expects System.Func](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31712588/1243762)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the term *top-level* has different meaning in different contexts.

Generally speaking, I'd use it whenever you have some structure that allows nesting to refer to the one position at the top that is not nested inside anything else.

For example, if you said "top-level parentheses" in an expression, it would refer to the outer-most pair of parentheses:

```
((1 + 2) * (3 * (8)))
^                   ^
```

When talking about functions and value bindings (and scope) in F#, it refers to the function that is not nested inside another function. So functions inside modules are top-level:

```
module Foo = 
  let topLevel n = 
    let nested a = a * 10
    10 + nested n
```

Here, `nested` is nested inside `topLevel`.

In F#, functions and values defined using `let` can appear inside modules or inside classes, which complicates things a bit - I'd say only those inside modules are *top-level*, but that's probably just because they are public by default.

The `do` keyword works similarly - you can nest it (although almost nobody does that) and so top-level `do` that allows `STAThread` attribute is the one that is not nested inside another `do` or `let`:

```
module Foo =
  [<STAThread>] 
  do
    printfn "Hello!"
```

Bud it is not allowed on any `do` nested inside another expression:

```
do
  [<STAThread>] 
  do 
    printfn "Hello!"
  printfn "This is odd notation, I know..."
```